# How do machine instructions know the length and size of certain data?

Tags: types, cpu, cpu-architecture, instructions

How do machine instructions know the length and size of certain data?  Ex:bool,char, etc?  Is any data type processed by compiler in ARM architecture all one word length in memory?

Comment: answer: https://www.swansontec.com/sintel.html

Answer (score 2):

On x86 at least, this is coded directly into the instruction. An instruction operating on 64-bit values is different from one operating on 32-bit values.

Comment: Has the compiler allocated different bits of data to different types of registers?

Comment: The guy who designed the instruction set did that.